# Azure devops ci/cd for .net core console application

Tags: azure-devops, cicd

I have one .net core (3.1) console application which make few entries into database.

I want this application to be executed on dev,QA & prod environment.

How can I setup azure ci/cd pipeline for this execution so that it can be done without manual intervention?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to set different connection-strings in your CI/CD process: https://www.connectionstrings.com/store-and-read-connection-string-in-appsettings-json/ You can use Azure Key Vault for storing the connection-strings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Thanks Markus but I want insights on ci/cd pipeline like which task I need to use to run this utility

Comment: Check this https://medium.com/@aravindi.s.amarasinghe/azure-devops-ci-cd-pipelines-cf5d7cfe379e.